# Por que o resultado desse código em C da 55?

Tags: c, compilação

Queria saber por que o resultado desse código da 55, estou lendo no livro e não entendi, compilei no codeblocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, soma = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {

    soma = soma + i;
}
printf("Soma %d\n", soma);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está acumulando o contador na variável `soma`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro acrescentar a seguinte linha dentro do for:

```
printf("i vale %d Soma vale%d\n",i, soma);
```

Ficando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i, soma = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        soma = soma + i;
        printf("i vale %d Soma vale %d\n",i, soma);
    }
    printf("Soma %d\n", soma);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Então você vai saber que...

```
i vale 1 Soma vale 1  //1ª Iteração
i vale 2 Soma vale 3  //2ª Iteração
i vale 3 Soma vale 6  //3ª Iteração
i vale 4 Soma vale 10  //4ª Iteração
i vale 5 Soma vale 15  //5ª Iteração
i vale 6 Soma vale 21  //6ª Iteração
i vale 7 Soma vale 28  //7ª Iteração
i vale 8 Soma vale 36  //8ª Iteração
i vale 9 Soma vale 45  //9ª Iteração
i vale 10 Soma vale 55  //10ª Iteração
```

Quando você faz `soma = soma + i;` você incrementa o valor de soma, adicionando o que já tinha anteriormente.

Por exemplo, quando `i = 3` e `soma = 3`, então soma passará a valer 6 pois `soma recebe soma (que vale 3) + i (que vale 3)`

Recomendo a você que está começando que pegue um papel e lápis e escreva o valor de cada iteração dentro do laço for. Assim você vai compreender o que acontece em cada iteração.

Comment: `i + soma` ou `soma + i` é a mesma coisa. Você só deve ter cuidado com multiplicações e divisões, pois isto tem precedência sobre adição e subtração. O que está acontecendo é que a cada iteração `soma` muda de valor para `soma + i`. Imagine o operador `=` como uma atribuição. `soma` ganha um valor novo, que é `i` + o valor anterior de `soma`

Comment: Então é a soma da variável "soma" anterior mais o i.

Comment: Exatamente :) Espero ter ajudado. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, poste nos comentários.

Comment: Humm, é bom fazer comentários no código.

Comment: Sim, claro. Mas quando estava estudando algoritmos, eu fazia no papel. Acredite, é a melhor maneira de aprender. Ou então insira printf no código e botas a imprimir o valor das tuas variáveis.

Comment: @Avelino Bom dia, "Você só deve ter cuidado com multiplicações e divisões.. " Na verdade deve-se ter cuidado com divisões e SUBTRAÇÕES, afinal uma das propriedades da multiplicação é 'a ordem dos fatores não altera o produto' logo, na multiplicação, tanto faz a ordem ;)

Comment: @MarianaSempe quis dizer para ele ter cuidado com a [precedência de operadores](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/precedence.html). Como pode observar [neste link](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/precedence.html) multiplicação e divisão tem precedência sobre adição e subtração. Então se ele fizesse algo como `soma = i * j / k + l - m` a multiplicação e divisão seriam executadas antes da adição e subtração. Acho que você deve ter confudido `precedência de operadores` com a propriedade da `comutatividade`. Eu sei o que significam os dois.

Comment: @Avelino Eu sei o que é precedência e neste caso não se aplica, afinal não há mais de uma operação, apenas uma soma, logo o que importa no caso seria tomar cuidado com - e / por isso deduzi que tinha se equivocado. Outra coisa, editastes o comentário, não? hehe valeu

Comment: Não há como editar o comentário após 15 minutos, meus comentários foram há 2 dias. Eu bem que queria para explicar melhor o meu raciocínio. Só quis dar uma dica, pois ele é iniciante. Quando formulei minha resposta e escrevi estes comentários estava há umas 30 horas sem dormir (como estou agora) então eu que expliquei mal, reconheço isto. É só um mal entendido.

Comment: @Avelino cara, tranquilo, sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Bom vamos lá, você está fazendo um loop com a variável  `int i`
que na primeira iteração do `for` tem o valor de 1. 
Você assumiu também que `int soma` tem o valor 0.
O seu loop vai rodar ate `int i` alcançar o valor de 10, lembrando que você iniciou ele como 1 `for (i = 1;`  seu loop irá rodar enquanto `int i` for menor ou igual a 10 `i <= 10;`

Vamos simular agora seu **loop** passo a passo.

**Primeira Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 0  |   int i = 1   |  Resultado = 1`

**Segunda Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 1  |   int i = 2   |  Resultado = 3`

**Terceira Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 3  |   int i = 3   |  Resultado = 6`

**Quarta Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 6  |   int i = 4   |  Resultado = 10`

**Quinta Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 10  |   int i = 5   |  Resultado = 15`

**Sexta Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 15  |   int i = 6   |  Resultado = 21`

**Sétima Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 21  |   int i = 7   |  Resultado = 28`

**Oitava Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 28  |   int i = 8   |  Resultado = 36`

**Nona Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 36  |   int i = 9   |  Resultado = 45`

**Décima Iteração**

soma = soma + i; `Soma = 45  |   int i = 10   |  Resultado = 55`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, soma = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    {  
        soma = soma + i;
    }

    printf("Soma %d\n", soma);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sim, já entendi.

Comment: Boa resposta +1 [`PS:Interação != Iteração`](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/footnotes/interativo.html)